# Using the verb suggest as the word advise

Tags: word-usage

When we say

"I suggest Jamie to take the job "

We talk to HR departmant not to Jamie..So I would like to ask how can I give an advice somebody and tell somebody else what I said.

"His doctor advised him to take time off work" like in this sentence

I would like to say " I advised Jamie to take the job " using the verb suggest..
is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested to Jamie that he/she should take the job.

Suggested <- past tense

Jamie <- direct object pronoun

Adding the preposition 'to' clarifies the recipient of the action.

Adding should because it is a suggestion/advice and not a command.

Example: I told Jamie to take the job.

Another way, "I suggested to Jamie, "you should take the job."

Comment: @ David Thank you for your help:)How about this sentence?Is it ok and if it is, is there a difference between them?  " I suggested (that ) Jamie get the job "

Comment: This also works. Even though generically it has the same meaning, you are now placing a bit of emphasis on the suggestion. 'that' being a specific suggestion. As far as the use of 'get', you can't really suggest if they 'get' something because it is out of Jamie's and your control. It is the decision of the employer. I would use 'should take'. If it was your decision for Jamie to get the job, then you wouldn't need to suggest it necessarily. It would be more or less a forced suggestion. Employer: "I suggest you take the job." It leaves a sense that something will happen if they don't take it.

Comment: @ David Thank you for your help.Your answer is very informative and helpful.Actually I meant "apply" when I used the word "get"  but I've just read that using this structure sounds a bit rude and threatenig even when we say "I suggest you give him a call" so it sounds like it has similar meaning with " you had better" ..

Comment: But how about these sentence which I got from a ESL website.         The company suggested (that) we take an extra day off.

 



    She suggests (that) we go out for dinner after the movie.

    My parents suggested (that) I get a job after school.

    Her brother suggests (that) she study harder so she can get into a good university.

Comment: Second thought, 'that' depending on how your pause and place emphasis could also mean a specific Jamie. /I suggested... THAT Jamie should take the job./ vs. /I suggested that... Jamie should take the job./

Comment: Making a suggestion from an authoritative positiion where they have control of an outcome (if you don't follow their suggestion) in most cases sounds threatening. In this case, to seem less threatening use "I would prefer that...", "I would like it if..." but not suggest. Ultimately it would depend on context, tone and emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

"I suggest Jamie to take the job "  **X**

Although the pattern *verb a person to do something* is possible with many verbs, for example *advise, tell, order,* it is not possible with *suggest.* "*Suggest* is not followed by **object + infinitive**. ... *Suggest* is not normally followed by an indirect object without a preposition." (Michael Swan, 2005.570, *Practical English Usage*)

Possible patterns with *suggest* are:

*1. I suggested to Jamie that he **take** the job.*

*2. I suggested to Jamie that he **takes** the job.*

*3. I suggested to Jamie that he **took** the job*

*4. I suggested to Jamie that he **should take** the job*.

In (1), *take* is the subjunctive form, quite common in AmE but rather formal in BrE. It can be used whether the suggestion was made for an action in a time that is now past or for a present or future action.  (*I suggested he take it that day. I suggested he take it now/when it is offered next week*)

In (2), *takes* is the indicative form, present tense. This is commonly used in BrE if when the suggestion is made for a present or future action. (*I suggested he takes it now/next when it is offered next week*)

In (3), *took* is the indicative form, past tense. It can be used in BrE in a similar way to the present subjunctive (1).  (*I suggested he took it that day. I suggested he took it now/when it is offered next week*)

We often use *should* in suggestions in BrE, as in (4)  as an alternative to the present subjunctive. (*I suggested he should take it that day. I suggested he should take it now/when it is offered next week*)

Comment: @ Tunny.Thank you for your answer. When I wrote "I suggest Jamie to take the job " I imagined like I talk to someone from human resource departmant from the company where I work and I say that Jamie would be good choice..or I think I can say " I suggested Jamie to the company where I work". It is like "suggesting a doctor I trust to somebody ".Are these sentences ok ?

Comment: The first sentence is not possible. Read the first four lines of my answer. The second sentence is possible.

Comment: Or can we say " Could you suggest me to your company for  CEO position "